practical consideration of wildcard option and end of month option in treasury basis
I was told by a senior trader that you only play either wildcard or month end options in treasury basis. You do not attempt to do both, i.e., wildcard first and if it does not work, end of month. Something to do with liquidity in the delivery month... any idea why this could be the case ? It looks to me that you have to either targeting to play the wildcard option or the end of month option before you entre into the delivery month

it is a very different question. let me rephrase it @Dimitri Vulis. just made it clearer. could you please reopen it ? thank you.
